# SP2013 get List EmailAlias with JavaScript

Tags: 2013, list, rest, email, jsom

I've been struggling with a problem today that I wasn't able to solve.

I got a List which is Email Enabled (Calendar List) and has an Emailalias set (e.g.: cal@mysharepoint.local)

Now I want to display the Emailadress of the List in my Listview.

I tried to get it via JSOM or REST but haven't yet managed to read out the Email Alias there.

Can anyone help me?
Greetings
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay with the help of one of my collegues I was able to find a solution. Its possible to get the EmailAlias of the List using the schemaXml of the list.

Below is a pretty basic code snippet that will output the current list emailalias when put on the listview via Content Editor WP.

```
<script>
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
    ctx.load(list, 'SchemaXml')
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        var xml = list.get_schemaXml().toString();
        alert(xml.substring(xml.indexOf('EmailAlias')).split('"')[1]);
    },function(){});
</script>
```